# Why we use "&(*" statement when double pointer to struct is an argument of a function?

Tags: c, pointers, tree, double

```
void instert(NODE**root, int value)
{
    ...
    insert(&(*root)->left,value);
    ...
}

void search(NODE*root, int value)
{
    ...
    search(root->left, value);
    ...
}
```

Why we use "&" here: insert(&(*root)->left,value);
But we do not use "&" here:  search(root->left, value);

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence. If it's not that, your question is unclear to me. `insert` needs a `NODE **`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An extra level of indirection is added to `insert` function so that it could modify the pointer. This is not necessary in case of the `search` function, because it never modifies the pointer passed to it.

Specifically, there needs to be a place in the `insert` function that does something like this:

```
*root = malloc(sizeof(NODE));
(*root)->left = NULL;
(*root)->right = NULL;
(*root)->value = value;
```

This would modify the pointer which is pointed to by the pointer to pointer.

Note that it is possible to avoid this extra level of indirection by returning the new value of the pointer from `insert`, like this:

```
NODE* insert(NODE*root, int value) {
    ...
    root->left = insert(root->left, value);
    ...
}
```

However, this changes the way in which all callers must call `insert`, including the top-level caller: rather than writing

```
insert(&root, value);
```

he would be forced to write

```
root = insert(root, value);
```

Comment: I know that double pointer is modyfing something. But I wonder why "&" is here insert(&(*root)->left,value); but it is not here search(root->left, value);

Comment: @AdrianPrzemysławDrozdowski Well, any pointer means "modifying something". Double pointer usually means "modifying some pointer". In your case, the pointer (single and double) is `root`. However, in the first case it would be more appropriate to call it something else - say, `p_root`, to make the difference explicit even in the name.

Answer (score 3):

The expression:

```
*root->left
```

Is equivalent to:

```
*(root->left)
```

Due to operator precedence.

So you need:

```
(*root)->left
```

If you want the `left` member that `*root` points to.

And then:

```
&(*root)->left
```

Is the pointer to the `left` member of `*root`, which is then of type `NODE **`, what the `insert` function requires.

Answer (score 0):

`&(*` isn't a statement.

It is parts of the `&`-operator being applied to the expression `(*root)->left`.